# Crash in C++ setter function

Tags: c++, string, getter-setter

I have a class that's instantiated by two different classes as below:
I am hitting a crash in set_url() function in following code. Unable to decide why?

```
class UrlAction {
    String url;
    bool action;
public:
   UrlAction() : action(false) {};

   void operator=(const UrlAction &from);

   inline String get_url() {
       return url;
   }
   inline void set_url(String from_url) {
       this->url = from_url;
   }
   inline bool get_action() {
       return action;
   }
   inline void set_action(bool act) {
       this->action = act;
   }
};

class A {
public:
    Vector<UrlAction>   _url_act_list;
};
class B {
public:
    Vector<UrlAction>   _url_act_list;
};
foo() {
    A a;
    B b;
    Vector<String> temp_vect;
    temp_vect.push_back("xxxxx.com");
    temp_vect.push_back("yyyyy.com");
    temp_vect.push_back("zzzzz.com");
    temp_vect.push_back("wwwww.com");
    temp_vect.push_back("vvvvv.com");

    for (int i = 0; i < temp_vect.size(); i++) {
        a._url_act_list[i].set_url(temp_vect[i]); //This is the line causing crash
    }
}
```

I also have written a '=' operator overloader that assigns two objects of type UrlAction.

Comment: You are accessing `_url_act_list` out of bounds.

Comment: Also, when using non std versions of string's and vector's it would be good at least to include information, where they come from.

Comment: What is `Vector`?  What is `String`?  C++ has `std::vector` and `std::string`, so what are these versions that start with capital letters?

Comment: To start solving these kinds of problems on your own, you can add `cout` statements to your code to view the values of variables and see if they are what you expect.

Comment: Yes, String and Vector STLs used here are custom and non-std.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Vector<UrlAction> _url_act_list` is instantiated when you declare `a`, but the size of `_url_act_list` is 0 initially. Thus, when you try to index into it, you get a segfault causing the program to crash.

Comment: Probably right, but hard to say for sure until OP posts their `Vector` class.

Answer (score 2):

`a._url_act_list` is empty. You could

- either define a constructor that receives the size and you use that size to create the `vector` (in `A` and `B`)
- or `resize` the vector accordingly just before accessing it, i.e. before the `for` loop
- or just `push_back` the elements into the vector

The first option might look like this:

```
A::A(size_t size) : { _url_act_list.resize(size) }
B::B(size_t size) : { _url_act_list.resize(size) }
```

The second option might look like this:

```
a.resize(temp_vect.size());
for (int i = 0; i < temp_vect.size(); i++) {
    a._url_act_list[i].set_url(temp_vect[i]); //This is the line causing crash
}
```

The third option might look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp_vect.size(); i++) {
    UrlAction url_action;
    url_action->set_url(temp_vect[i]);
    a._url_act_list.push_back(url_action); //This is the line causing crash
}
```

I believe your code may be designed better. Should `_url_act_list` really be public? Wouldn't it be easier (considering option 3) to have a `URLAction(string s)` constructor ? There are some things that kind of bug me, though that is not part of this question.

Comment: Thank you. Added a constructor        UrlAction(String from_url, bool act)  that sets the url and action when creating an object and then pushing it in vector a. _url_act_list

Answer (score 1):

`a._url_act_list` is empty when you try to call `operator[]` for it. Consider replacing

```
a._url_act_list[i].set_url(temp_vect[i]); //This is the line causing crash
```

with

```
a._url_act_list.push_back({});
a._url_act_list.back().set_url(temp_vect[i]);
```

Comment: a.push_back(); ///what is pushed ??